# How do I prevent stacked drinking glasses from sticking together?

Tags: kitchen, efficiency, storage, glass

I don't have enough shelf space for each glass to sit separately.

I must stack them to fit. The problem is worse for some sets of drinking glasses than others. It might be because of their shape, texture, or weight. I don't know. I like them and want to keep and use them.

When I do this, nested glasses are sometimes hard to pull apart.

 Instead of finding good ways to get them apart, I'd like to prevent them sticking together.

I've tried stacking them on the shelf with the open ends both up and with the open ends down.
I get the same result.

What do you do to **prevent** this common problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on actually stacking the glasses:

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but a strip of paper or cloth wedged in between two stacked glasses will both prevent the glasses from “sticking” (pressure problem) and from chipping.

I would rather build a “flat pyramid”, not nesting the glasses, but placing one glass on top of two (or three, in 3d, if it fits better) other glasses. If you feel that’s too wobbly (again, it depends on the glasses’ geometry), a thin board/piece of plywood, plexiglass or similar on the lower layer can be an impromptu shelf. Just flip it up and lean on the back of the shelf if you need to take out the lower layer of glasses.

Comment: The thin strip of paper was EXACTLY the solution. The pyramid took up too much space and didn't allow more that two layers. The "shelf" was too fussy. Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

Although you already selected the answer you like, I have another option that works if you have different kinds of glasses. Rather than stacking glasses of the same type together, stack glasses of different types together. The varying sizes and shapes will be less prone to getting stuck inside of each other. For example, you could stack your largest glasses on the "outside" of the stack, and smaller ones inside that, and the smallest in the very inside of the stack.